# How to disable chrome's save address popup in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to disable chrome's save address popup in selenium using python?

Have tried searching for an argument for the add_arguments() function avaialble for the Options() class but unable to find any solution. The following is also added but it disables the notification permission popup but not the address one

```
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
```

Comment: you can try to use: chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-autofill-dropdown")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-save-password-bubble")

Comment: also give this a shot: option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2 
})

Comment: @pcalkins, I have tried your suggestion but it didnt work, thanks though

Comment: @DimaBerezovskyi, I tried your suggesstion but it didnt work, thanks though